# regular expression to select after n number of occurences of certain character

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pattern-matching

Creating some regex expressions here. I was wondering if I could get some pointers on how to go about selecting a string after n occurences of one character and before the next occurence of a certain char.

for instance

```
xyz|yui|i want to select this.
```

In this example I am wanting to select after the 2nd "|" and before the next ".". So the text I want to match is "i want to select this".

I appreciate any pointers thanks.

**UPDATE**

To be more specific on why I need to do this above, there is more text after the period at the end of "I want to select this.". Basically this is undelimited content which I am trying to delimit. Thusfar I have been able to delimt the first two fields, now I need to be able to select only text after the last "|" and before the next period and add a "|" character to the end. So the desired result would be

```
xyz|yui|i want to select this.|
```

Sorry for not being more specific on the outcome and I hope this clears it up a bit. Thanks for the info, its super.

Comment: Do you want this regex in PHP or in MySQL?

Comment: php would be great as I know mysql is quite limited in its support. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a group which contains the repeating part `([^|]+\|)` here, which can be set to appear exactly two times `{2}`, then you need to match the rest `(.*)`:

```
^([^|]+\|){2}(.*?)\.
```

*Update*

You can ungroup it as @Karolis mentioned with `?:`

```
^(?:[^|]+\|){2}(.*?)\.
```

WIth the first regexp the second match will be yours, with the second it will be the first.

Comment: @Karolis's edit sets the first group to a non-selection group.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto I added `\.` and corrected `\|`. Also added `?:`, but it's not the most important thing

Comment: The OP added "there is more text after the period at the end", so the Regex should be `^(?:[^|]+\|){2}(.*?)\.`.

Comment: One last part to this guys, how would you go about excluding certain things from the match. Rockets comment on this answer coupled with the answers are right on the money. Only one issue, sometimes there may be one period in the form "Co." before the period that I require to select to, is it possible to ignore that "Co." in the matching. Thanks again I appreciate this.

Comment: @jiraiya: Does it always end in `.|`?  If so, then you can do `^(?:[^|]+\|){2}(.*?)\.\|`.

Comment: no, unfortunately not, I'm trying to add the "|" to delimit already existing text. I'm so close now. This ^(?:[^|]+\|){2}(.*?)\. is perfect, I just need to be able to tell it to ignore but also include the "Co." that occurs in some of the fields and continue onto the period we want.

Comment: got it, i cobined Korvins comment for ignoring Co. to get ^(?:[^|]+\|){2}(.*?)[^(?:Co)]\. We are lauging thanks guys ye are gentlemen.

Comment: Thanks for the sample Rocket, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Aww why does he get the best answer =[

Comment: Just to confirm that the answer was gotten to from all the guys help here on the page. thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

Your regex would look like this:

```
/^(?:.+?\|){2}(.+?[^(Co)]\.)/
```

## PHP

```
<?php
    preg_match('/^(?:.+?\|){2}(.+?[^(Co)]\.)/','xyz|yui|This is a Co. sentence. Ending before this clause.',$out);
    echo $out[1];
?>
```

**HOWEVER**

You should explode by the pipe character and access the respective information like that:

```
$stuff = explode('|','xyz|yui|i want to select this.');
echo $stuff[2];
```

Comment: great thanks. Perhaps I should explain more, what I am trying to do, I will edit the question above to be more descriptive. But these suggestions are almost there I think.

Comment: Hi Korvin thanks but the selection stops if there is a period in the content between the first two "|" delimters. Tested it in regexr, maybe I'm doing something wrong. My text above is sample so I'm sorry if that part was not clear, I only want it to look for a period after the 2nd "|". I appreciate your help, cheers.

Comment: apologies Korvin, I was making a mistake in it. I was testing it in regexr. Thanks again. I tried to flag both as answers but it wont let me so I flagged the one above because ye have all commented in it. thanks again.

Comment: Doesn't work. Your subexpression: `[^(Co)]` is not doing what you think it is. Change your test string to: `"xyz|yui|This is a Co. (sentence). Ending before this clause."` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```php
$text = 'xyz|yui|i want to select Co. this. But not this.';
$re = '/# Match stuff after nth occurance of a char.
    ^               # Anchor to start of string.
    (?:[^|]*\|){2}  # Everything up through 2nd "|"
    (               # $1: Capture up through next "."
      [^.]*         # Zero or more non-dot.
      (?:           # Allow dot if in "Co.".
        (?<=Co)     # If dot is preceded by "Co",
        \.          # then allow this dot.
        [^.]*       # Zero or more non-dot.
      )*            # Zero or more "Co." dots allowed.
      \.            # First dot that is not "Co."
    )               # End $1: Capture up through next "."
    /ix';
$text = preg_replace($re, '$0|', $text);
echo $text;
```

**Edit 2011-09-28 10:00 MDT:** Added ability to skip over dots in: `"Co."`
**Edit 2011-09-28 10:30 MDT:** Changed to use `preg_replace()` to insert | after dot.

Comment: Nice. Only one issue, sometimes there may be one period in the form "Co." before the period that I require to select to, is it possible to ignore that "Co." in the matching while still including it, i.e. skip over it and match to the period that we want. Thanks again I appreciate this.

Comment: Just change `([^.]*\.)` to `(.*)\.` (or `(.*)\.\|` if the string ends with `.|`).